# How to add a gradient to a view in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

I am learning about the basics of Swift and iOS App Development.
I want to create a gradient page in my application.
I found this code online:

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer() // Line 1
gradient.frame = view.bounds // Line 2
gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor] // Line 3    
view.layer.addSublayer(gradient) // Line 4
```

What is the meaning of the above code? I am using Swift 4.

I understood Line 3. It's deciding what colours should be there in the gradient and in what order. Please explain the rest of the code.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some Playground code you can play with:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import XCTest
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

// this is the UIView we're going to use.
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))

// this is making a CoreAnimation gradient layer
let gradient = CAGradientLayer() // Line 1

// this is setting the dimensions of the gradient to the
// same as the view that will contain it
gradient.frame = view.bounds // Line 2

// this is setting the gradient from and to colors
gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor] // Line 3

// this is adding the gradient to the view hierarchy so you can see it
view.layer.addSublayer(gradient) // Line 4

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

The output is:

[image: gradient in a playground]

Answer (score 2):

The first line create an object of `CAGradientLayer` which encapsulates the gradient properties:

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer() // Line 1
```

The second line (gives the rect the gradient will be shown in the parent view) assign the frame of view to the frame of the gradient that will hold it:

```
gradient.frame = view.bounds // Line 2
```

frame is a rect with x,y,width,height

the last line

```
view.layer.addSublayer(gradient) // Line 4
```

add the gradient layer above the layer of the parent view, so content of gradient is shown above the view , note if this line is commented, you'll not be able to see the gradient as it's created on the fly.